# Check for a unique value within a count, but get all results

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to create a single query which, similar to stack overflow, will give me the number of votes, but also make sure that the currently viewing user can't upvote again if they've already upvoted.

my query currently looks like

```
SELECT cid, text, COUNT(votes.parentid)  FROM comments LEFT JOIN votes ON comments.cid=votes.parentid AND votes.type=3 WHERE comments.type=0 AND comments.parentid='$commentParentid' GROUP BY comments.cid
```

But I'm completely stumpted on how to add the check to see if the userid is in the votes table.

The other option is to add a seperate query where

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE userid='$userid' AND parentid='$commentParentid' AND type=3
```

I'm just realizing I'm so lost with this that I don't even really know what tags to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cid, text, COUNT(votes.parentid), 
    COUNT(IF(votes.userid='$userid',1,NULL)) = 0 AS can_vote
FROM comments 
LEFT JOIN votes ON comments.cid=votes.parentid AND votes.type=3 
WHERE comments.type=0 AND comments.parentid='$commentParentid' 
GROUP BY comments.cid
```

This should give you a flag `can_vote` based on the number of times the user has voted on the comment, if you insist on doing this in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Iggy, That worked very well, and added very little time to the query (so far on a small dataset). Out of curiosity, the way you say 'if I insist on doing this in sql', is there another way you would recommend?

Comment: You are basically right to worry about performance, a single complex query might take longer than two or three separate ones and some number crunching in your code.